# Casting of char in ruby is different in C?

Tags: c, ruby

I tried to convert a decimal to char in ruby and in C the results are below:

```
In Ruby: 129.chr is equals to "\x81"
       : 106.chr is equals to "j"

In C   : (char)(129) is equals to "\201"
       : (char)(106) is equals to "j"
```

Why when converting 129 in C it turns out that it converts 129 to its oct value? Is there any way that ruby will behave like that?

Comment: Is there any difference? `129 == 0201` and `0201 == 0x81`

Comment: Can you give us the actual C code for your printing? I can't say anything till I know what you're actually doing here.

Comment: @Stefan yes there's difference, the format on how they output the casting.

Comment: @DallaRosa here -> printf((char)(129)); will output \201 (oct format) while when I do -> printf((char)(106)); will output 'j' (symbol). while in ruby all the output is just in symbol or char

Answer (score 1):

Correction: in C, character constant is `'j'`, not `"j"` (string literal)

In C, character constants are of type `int`, there is no difference between `106` (decimal integer), `\152`(character constant in octal), and `'j'` (character constant).

In Ruby, to get the octal string, use [`Fixnum#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s):

```
129.to_s(8)
# => "201"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yu Hao, I know that there's no difference between those 3 types, and I know how to convert in octal. What my question is how will ruby behave like C ,that when I cast 129 to chr it will directly convert it to 201.

Comment: @wirepin I have no idea how you do it in C because `(char)(129)` is an rvalue, it's just a value, how it's shown in output depends on how you print it. As for Ruby, I think string literals use hexadecimal format instead of octal because it's easier to use and less confusing.

Comment: @YuHao: mruby uses octal instead of hex unlike all other implementations I know of. But, as mentioned, it doesn't matter, since it's just a different representation of the same string.

Comment: @cremno, I am looking for a solution that ruby conversion of chr will behave like the casting of char in C, what am I doing is to integrate this in a previous system that was made in C and the parsing of message in that system only accepts the format that C output in casting char.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a disclaimer:

**What's printed by a some function has nothing to do with the actual value. The stored value is the same independently of what's output.**

The above was already said but I had to just make it very clear once more.

Now let's the real stuff.

I asked for the code you used because I know that C is not like ruby where you just do `print 129` and things work out just fine. The C function printf has the signature below

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

Which means you can't just pass the number (or char variable) like that and C will do the magic for you. You actually have to pass the format as string and then values you want to be injected there.

I actually tried what you said just for the sake of being really sure of what I was saying: The only thing you get is `Segmentation Fault 11`

However, I did find something interesting out there:

Below is a piece of code of some various ways of representing the same value in C and its output:

https://gist.github.com/dallarosa/412235a6101e5fda3bed

```
$ ./test_printf
----
(char)129
----
char: �
octal: 37777777601
hexa: ffffff81
unsigned: 4294967169
binary: 11111111111111111111111110000001
----
129
----
char: �
octal: 201
hexa: 81
unsigned: 129
binary: 00000000000000000000000010000001
```

This compiler defines char's to be a signed type with one byte size, when you cast 129 to char you end up getting a negative value.

FIY, this is a Macbook Pro with OS X 10.9.5